# Error showing when installing cern root-6.26 in ubuntu 22.10

Tags: software-installation

```
cmake --build . --target install -j4
[  0%] Built target VDT
[  0%] Built target AFTERIMAGE
[  0%] Built target TBB
[  0%] Performing build step for 'LZMA'
[  0%] Built target copymodulemap
[  0%] Built target move_header_roofit_hs3
[  0%] Built target OPENUI5
CMake Error at /home/baba/root/LZMA-prefix/src/LZMA-stamp/LZMA-build-Release.cmake:49 (message):
  Command failed: 2

   '/usr/bin/gmake'

  See also

    /home/baba/root/LZMA-prefix/src/LZMA-stamp/LZMA-build-*.log


gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/LZMA.dir/build.make:86: LZMA-prefix/src/LZMA-stamp/LZMA-build] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7377: CMakeFiles/LZMA.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  0%] Built target builtin_nlohmann_json_incl
[  0%] Built target PCRE
[  0%] Building C object builtins/xxhash/CMakeFiles/xxhash.dir/xxhash.c.o
[  0%] Linking C static library ../../lib/libxxhash.a
[  0%] Built target xxhash
gmake: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
```

--The the LZMA-build-err.log  showing

```
--/home/baba/root/LZMA-prefix/src/LZMA/build-aux/missing: line 81: aclocal-1.15: command not found
WARNING: ‘aclocal-1.15’ is missing on your system.
You should only need it if you modified ‘acinclude.m4’ or
‘configure.ac’ or m4 files included by ‘configure.ac’.
The ‘aclocal’ program is part of the GNU Automake package:
http://www.gnu.org/software/automake
It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf
http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/
http://www.perl.org/
gmake[3]: *** [Makefile:514: aclocal.m4] Error 127

---
```

Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same error. Please help me.

CMake Error at /home/joydev/Apps/root/root_build/AFTERIMAGE-prefix/src/AFTERIMAGE-stamp/AFTERIMAGE-build-Release.cmake:49 (message):

Command failed: 2

'/usr/bin/gmake'

See also

```
/home/joydev/Apps/root/root_build/AFTERIMAGE-prefix/src/AFTERIMAGE-stamp/AFTERIMAGE-build-*.log
```

gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/AFTERIMAGE.dir/build.make:86: AFTERIMAGE-prefix/src/AFTERIMAGE-stamp/AFTERIMAGE-build] Error 1

gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5621: CMakeFiles/AFTERIMAGE.dir/all] Error 2

gmake: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2

joydev@joydev-VirtualBox:~/Apps/root/root_build$